# Install R package "sqldf" (RSQLite.extfuns) locally

Tags: r, sqldf, install.packages

I'm trying to install the R-package `sqldf` on a Linux-pc where I don't have root access.
When R tries to install the package `RSQLite.extfuns` it fails because the library `sqlite3ext.h` is missing. As i can't install the library globally i downloaded and compiled it in my home directory. But how can i tell `R` (or gcc) now where the library is located. It searches at `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/lib64/R/library/...` but I don't have access to those locations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See if this [guide](http://lamages.blogspot.com/2012/04/installing-r-packages-without-admin.html) helps.

Comment: You need to provide more information about how you're installing the package and your system setup - `sqlite3ext.h` is included in RSQLite and should be found automatically. Root access is definitely not required, but you may need to set the `R_LIBS` envvar in `~/.Renviron`.

Answer (score 2):

I was having some issues here too. I updated R to the latest version, updated all the packages, reinstalled the sqldf package and everything seemed to work. For me it was just that something was outdated

Comment: The latest version of RSQLite incorporates RSQLite.extfuns so that package was removed from the active CRAN packages.  It really is just a matter of ensuring that one is using the latest version of all packages.